# Getting NaNs after appending one Pandas DataFrame to another one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting NaNs after appending one DataFrame to another one. I have tried multiple things, but nothing has helped me get the resulting value in the last column.

**My code:**

```
prod_prices = np.array([3])
prod_prices

prod_days = np.array([13,9,7,15]).reshape(1,4)
prod_days

df_week_sales = pd.DataFrame(prod_days,
                 index=["Apple"],
                columns=["Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs"])
df_week_sales

weekly_total = prod_prices.dot(df_week_sales)
weekly_total

weekly_total_sliced = weekly_total[:1]
weekly_total_sliced

df_weekly_total_sliced = pd.DataFrame(weekly_total_sliced)
df_weekly_total_sliced

df_week_sales["Total Rev.($)"] = pd.DataFrame(df_weekly_total_sliced)
df_week_sales
```

**My Expectation:**

```
         Mon    Tues    Wed    Thurs    Total Rev.($)
Apple    13     9       7      15       37
```

Comment: Nopes. That doesn't help. It gives an error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (5, 1)

Comment: Just replace the respective line with: df_week_sales["Total Rev.($)"] = weekly_total_sliced

Comment: Yes, I tried that too at first. But that too doesn't help me and gives NaN in the last column i.e. Total Rev.($)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
df_week_sales["Total Rev.($)"] = pd.DataFrame(df_weekly_total_sliced)
```

To:

```
df_week_sales["Total Rev.($)"] = float(df_weekly_total_sliced[0]) # or int(df_weekly_total_sliced[0])
```

Or:

```
df_week_sales["Total Rev.($)"] = pd.DataFrame(df_weekly_total_sliced).values.astype(float)
```

Output:

```
        Mon Tues Wed  Thurs Total Rev.($)
Apple   13  9     7   15       39.0
```

Comment: How did float made it work? I mean what is the concept here?

Comment: @WebDevelopmentLabs `df_weekly_total_sliced[0]` type is `pandas.series.series`, `float(df_weekly_total_sliced[0])` cast its type to `float`

Answer (score 1):

You struggling with the concept that pandas does intrinsic data alignment.   Meaning that if you perform an operation on two dataframes, pandas will align operations based on the row indexes and column headers.   A fix to your problem is to drop the indexing from one of your dataframe creating a numpy array and set the value in the first dataframe using that numpy array.

```
df_week_sales["Total Rev.($)"] = df_weekly_total_sliced.to_numpy()
df_week_sales
```

Output:

```
       Mon  Tues  Wed  Thurs  Total Rev.($)
Apple   13     9    7     15             39
```

You really don't need the middle step at all.

```
df_week_sales["Total Rev.($)"] = weekly_total[:1]
```

Will work also.

Comment: it throws an error without that middle step: ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (3)

Comment: You need to slice the right side equal to the rows in  your dataframe on the leftside.